# How to store whole book text (written in Arabic/Urdu language) in MongoDB , such a way that I can search text from it later?

Tags: mongodb, search, arabic, urdu

I want to store text of a book (written in Arabic/Urdu language) in MongoDB in the best possible way so that I can search any word from it, because I have to make a Mobile App where user will enter a search string and I will show him the best match accordingly.
Note: Every thing in app and DB will be in Arabic & Urdu language.

### I expect someone will suggest about:

1. How should I store the whole book's text (format and way to store)?
2. Guideline about how I will search that text on the base of user search string?

And any thing else you think is necessary to know for me before starting this project?

Comment: Did got the solution of arabic language. Please let me know if you have any one.